# Update parse column

Tags: sdk, lua, parse-platform, coronasdk

I'm new to parse and I have a problem with the score column on my parse.com table called User.

Here is have my login function and after the users log in successfully, I have this function that is supposed to update the score while the user plays.

```
local parse = require( "mod_parse" )
local ego = require "ego"
local saveFile = ego.saveFile
local loadFile = ego.loadFile
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------

 _G.score = 1


_G.highscore = loadFile ("highscores.txt")


local function checkForFile ()
if highscore == "empty" then
highscore = 0

saveFile("highscores.txt", highscore)
end
end
checkForFile()

--Print the current highscore
print ("Highscore is", highscore)

-----------------------------------------------
dataTable = { ["score"] = tonumber(highscore) }


function onSystemEvent (event)
if _G.score > tonumber(_G.highscore) then --We use tonumber as highscore is a string when loaded
saveFile("highscores.txt", _G.score)

parse:updateObject( "objectId", dataTable, onSystemEvent )

end
end
 _G.timer1=timer.performWithDelay(100, addToScore, 0)
```

The functions compare the `score` with the highscore and if score is higher than the `highscore` updates `highscore` with the new value.

I'm having trouble with the `parse:updateObject` function. I have a column called `score` on parse that I'm trying to update with the new highscore. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to save the object by calling the updateObject method, which I think requires you to know the objectID of the object you wish to save. I'm guessing that you tried to use "objectId", but that is certainly not the correct objectID. Farther than this, I can not help you as I do not know LUA.

I'm guessing you need some sort of ParseObject that you can save a new row. [I recommend that you take a look at the Parse SDKs, they explain it very well](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#objects).